# 2 form actions in interspire email marketer

Tags: php, forms, email

My client is using interspire email marketer, which generate html form, and save all data into crm database.
In the form, there is a postcode area, my client wants to send email alert to different department based on this postcode. 
I am thinking to create a seperate php file to match the postcode and send email alert.
But there is already a form.php in action. How can I add another action? Or is there any better way to achieve this?

Many Many thanks.
Below is the form code:

```
    <form name="ppt_form" class="ppt-form" method="post" action="http://na03.mypinpointe.com/form.php?form=332" id="frmSS332">
<p><span class="required">*</span>Your Email Address:<br />
<input type="text" class="email" name="email" fid="e" fname="Email" ftype="Email" reqd="1"/></p>

<p>Phone:<br />
<input type="text" name="CustomFields[8]" id="CustomFields_8_332" value="" fid="8" fname="Phone" size='50'></p>
<p>Postal: <br />
<input type="text" name="CustomFields[20]" id="CustomFields_20_332" value="" fid="20" fname="Postal" size='50'></p>

<p><input type="button" class="update-button" value="Submit"/></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I leave the form with 1 action. 
and add a ajax on button click.